# Filter entities by server function in Entity Framework?

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want EF to use a T-SQL table-value function to filter entities.

The function returns list of CompanyID so that EF can add a where statement like

```
...WHERE CompanyID IN (SELECT CompanyID FROM dbo.BySearchOptions({0},{1}))
```

So that later I can create an extension method like

```
IQueryable<Company> BySearchOptions(this IQueryable<Company, SearchOptions options)
```

and chain it with others like

```
var companies = Entities.Companies.
    Where(someconde).BySearchOptions(myOptionsObject).OrderBy.Whatever...
```

Is it possible?

**EDIT:** I know there is Entity SQL, so that Where() method can use ESQL strings and not predicates. Can Entity SQL be used to apply a t-sql function?

Answer (score 1):

The EF supports mapping SQL functions, but not (in EF 4) functions which return table values.

One alternative is to use [ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx) and pass T-SQL.

But you wouldn't be able to further compose the query, as you ask.

A possible workaround is to put the SQL query in a DB server view.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter by the function, by placing the select statement in a stored procedure and then calling the stored procedure from EF.

Probably not the elegant solution you are looking for, but it would work.

Comment: Thanks, but I want the filter to be chained with other where clauses used in joins, groups, etc.